# How do you store test data into nosql document database for quick read?

Tags: database, mongodb, dynamic, database-design, nosql

I am currently migrating our currently test data that is stored in excel files to a database. Because the type of data in the test results are going to grow we decided to go with nosql instead of sql.

I was planning on using a document database to store the data in but realized I'm not entirely sure how to store the data for it to be efficiently read.

The idea is that you have unique keys that help you find the data you are looking for quicker.

The data columns in the excel are:

- Date
- Model of device
- Version of software
- Type of test
- Bunch of test data from the test run.

Would a nested document be used for data could be read quickly.

i.e. [Type of test] -> [Date] -> [Model of device] -> [Version of software] -> [Bunch of test data]

Am I even using the right database type?

Comment: What do you mean with grow? More rows? If the data is well represented in columns, nosql wouldn't be a great choice, I'd pick a relational.

Comment: @mmontoya edited my question to not use the term columns as it might be misleading. From what I understand nosql allows for dynamic data structure schema. We don't want to be locked into a fixed data schema.